# Training neural nets: is it important that the data is randomly sorted?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Let's say I have a neural network that classifies data into A, B or C.
I've heard that it's bad to train the network with data from one class at a time, e.g. `A,A,A,...,B,B,B,...,C,C,C`. Now, is there a problem with other patterns in the data? For example `A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,...` and so forth.

Comment: The order of the data does make a difference. Determining the optimal order is actually a research problem called [curriculum learning](http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2009_curriculum_icml.pdf). If you have any questions after reading the paper I'll try to answer.

Comment: Specifically, I'm training a character classifier. As there is no easy way to automatically determine the difficulty for each picture (that I know of), and therefore no way of sorting the pictures internally in each class by difficulty, does it then make sense to sort the classes themselves by difficulty? One could imagine that classifying `O`, `o` and `I` is easier than `E` and `F`.

Comment: That sounds sensible to me.

Comment: After thinking about it there may be ways to roughly assess the difficulty of a picture. Signal-to-Noise ratio comes to mind, but I don't know much about such analysis and it would depend on the data set. I'm working with the [chars74k image data set](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/)

Comment: Simple random sorting would be the standard and should be sufficient for most tasks. At least try this before moving on to more complex methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is important that the data is randomly ordered. You want to remove patterns of how you descent along the cost function because such patterns can increase the likelihood of overfitting. It's easiest to explain on `A,A,A, ... B,B,B ...` pattern. Here the network is given an opportunity to adapt to peculiarities of the first training example before moving further. And the goal of training is not to adapt to peculiarities but to find features that generalize well. So it seems that a better idea is to expose the network to a different example in each iteration.

Most research works that I've seen simply randomize the order of examples in each epoch. But it seems sensible to think that a useful pattern might in fact exist. Perhaps one that focuses on maximizing the variety of features that the network is exposed to with each subsequent iteration.

Comment: I've not heard of randomizing the order each epoch before. Do you know of any comparisons between a static but random order and randomizing each epoch?

Comment: @tsorn: Randomising on each epoch is common practice and some libraries will do that by default. Randomising order just once at the start is also common. I did a quick search but did not find any formal comparisons of the approaches.

Comment: I haven't seen any formal comparisons unfortunately. It'd be an interesting subject for an experiment.